# Integration giving different answers (trig substitution)

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Integrating $\sin^3x\cos^5x$, i get 2 different answers, using techniques that should both be valid.

[image: Approach A: split sin^3, B: split cos^5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one on the left has a sign error. Presumably you had let $w=\cos\theta$. Then $dw=-\sin\theta\,d\theta$.  So the answer on the left is off by a factor of $-1$.

After that is corrected, the answers will still *look* different. That is taken care of by the constant of integration. This sort of thing happens a lot, particularly with trigonometric functions, because of the many identities.

As a simpler example, both $-\cos^2 t+C$ and $\sin^2 t+C$ are correct answers to $\int 2\sin t\cos t\,dt$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Establish that $$\frac{\cos^8x-\sin^8x}8-\frac{\cos^6x-\sin^6x}6-\frac{\sin^4x}4$$ is a constant

If $u_n=\cos^nx-\sin^nx,$

$$(\cos^nx-\sin^nx)(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)=\cdots$$

$$\implies u_n=u_{n+2}+\cos^2x\sin^2x\cdot u_{n-2}$$

$$\implies u_{n+2}=u_n-\cos^2x\sin^2x\cdot u_{n-2}$$

Now, $u_0=0,u_2=\cos^2x-\sin^2x$

$$n=2\implies u_4=u_2-\cos^2x\sin^2x\cdot u_0=u_2$$

$$n=4\implies u_6=u_4-\cos^2x\sin^2x\cdot u_2=u_2(1-\cos^2x\sin^2x)$$

$$n=6\implies u_8=u_6-\cos^2x\sin^2x\cdot u_4=u_2(1-\cos^2x\sin^2x)-u_2=-u_2(\cos^2x\sin^2x)$$

If $f(x)=g(x)+C, f'(x)=g'(x)$